# Handle event on element that id is defined at run time

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling

I want to handle event of element through it, since the id is defined at run time.

```
   <input type='submit' name='status' value='like' id='like'/>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

  $('#like').live('click',function(){
     alert('like');
      $(this).attr({'id':'unlick','value':'unlike'});
  })​​​​​​​​​​;

   $('input').delegate('#unlike','click',function(){
      alert('unlike');
      $(this).attr({'id':'lick','value':'like'});
  });
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R2X4c/) for the problem
​

Comment: First problem is you're mixing 'unlike' and 'unlick'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like below instead of writing 2 handlers,

**Markup:**

```
<input type='submit' name='status' class="like_status" value='like' id='like'/>
```

**JS**

```
$('.like_status').on('click',function(){
    alert(this.id);

    if (this.id == 'like') {      
       $(this).attr({'id':'unlike','value':'unlike'});
    } else {      
       $(this).attr({'id':'like','value':'like'});
    }
});
```

Or you can simply use `this.id` and `this.value` instead of jQuery functions.

```
$('.like_status').on('click',function(){
    var btnTxt = (this.id == 'like')?'unlike': 'like';
    this.id = btnTxt;
    this.value = btnTxt;  //Or some other text.
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/R2X4c/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Some typos and you can use `.on` for both like and unlike.

Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/CgKwt/2/

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: It's not working when changing the id to unlike, it still handle the like event!

Comment: @PalAla ah didn't test it when changed it from `.live` to `.on`, I've updated the link now.

Answer (score 0):

Captain Typo strikes again. Replace `unlick` with `unlike` and use `live()` for the second handler, too:

```
$('#like').live('click',function(){
    alert('like');
    $(this).prop('id', 'unlike').val('unlike');
});

$('#unlike').live('click',function(){
    alert('unlike');
    $(this).prop('id', 'like').val('like');
});
```

You should also use `.prop()` to set the id and `.val()` to set the value.

Oh, and consider not changing IDs but storing the flag (like/unlike) in a data attribute and check it inside the event handler. Then you don't need live events or delegates but can simply bind a regular event.

Comment: Of course it doesn't handle the event if you set the id to `unlick` but check for events on `unlike`.

Comment: Obligatory: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.